# Modal dialog with dropdown list is not fading out right away after dismissal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got an angular app and I integrated it with UI Bootstrap project. I'm using regular

The modal dialog with dropdown containing 750 records, when one of the items is selected and clicked "Ok" or "Cancel", the modal and the overlay fades out without any delay.

`Here's the plunker:`[Modal dialog with 750 records](http://plnkr.co/edit/F7kiIJwq26uAqpBBrVjs?p=preview)

If the modal dialog with dropdown containing around 10k+ records, and one of the items is selected from the list. Clicking "Ok" or "Cancel" is not hiding the modal dialog right away, instead I'm having a 8-10 second delay on Chrome, I've not tested on IE yet.

`Here's the plunker:`[Modal dialog with 10k+ records](http://plnkr.co/edit/yAOgdTVtf2uHWkSIWIQl?p=preview)

Question: Why I'm having performance hit with more data?

Comment: 10K records!! Are you serious? Which user will navigate through them? It is performance hit. You are rendering 10K ``<option>`` nodes. You are having a performance hit, because the browser needs to maintain those 10K ``<option>`` nodes and render them. BTW 750 ``<option>`` are also way to impractical, from usability perspective.

Comment: Dude your question has become famous :P https://www.facebook.com/bluecollared/photos/a.161429497358109.1073741826.161426044025121/317911805043210/?type=1&theater

Comment: Haha, wow. [I took that screenshot](https://twitter.com/Chevex/status/494613545707794433) and posted it on twitter saying I got a little chuckle. I didn't expect it to get passed around like that. Sorry orif :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are slowing the whole entire browser down by grabbing the DOM by the neck and pouring 10,000 `<option>` nodes down its throat. You need to [lazy load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) your data somehow. Ever noticed on sites like Twitter, Facebook, and others that when you scroll to the bottom of the page it will begin loading more records from the server? Good apps will start to garbage collect old records that have been scrolled up as well.

When you scroll through your Facebook news feed it's not loading all your friends post since 2007 into the browser all at the same time. Once a maximum number of posts exists in the DOM Facebook will start removing the oldest ones you scrolled up to make room for more and grab fresh posts from the server so you can continue scrolling. You can even see your browser scroll bar jump up as you scroll down because more posts are being added to the DOM.

No browser is going to be able to handle that much data. The browser is not a database. I'm amazed your plunker with 10k records is as performant as it is! Haha. A dropdown is not what you want to display that data. You're going to have to sit down and think of a better way to show that data to the user. My first thought is to provide a filterable list that initially contains the top 25 most selected options or something, then typing in a search field causes it to load a new list from the server that matches the search criteria. Only you will know what your users will actually want, but I assure you it's not a dropdown list with 10k+ options.

Example:

[image]

Notice how the browser scroll bar jumps up a bit when it gets to the bottom. Twitter gets to the bottom and then loads more data to scroll through. It will eventually start cleaning up data at the top of the page as well if I scroll far enough.

Modern browsers can handle a lot, but 10,000+ `<option>` nodes is pushing it overboard.

Comment: Hi Alex, I think in my case the infinite scroll will not be the option to go. Because I need to show the data to be selected. Probably the "typeahead" (autocomplete) will be alternative

Comment: Yes of course. I wasn't really showing you infinite scroll as a potential solution. I was merely showing you that it is not common to dump that much data into a page at once and was demonstrating the concept of lazy-loading. The solution you go with will obviously have to conform to your situation :)

Answer (score 1):

The browser can handle a large number of values in a dropdown list, but a dropdown list isn't meant for such a task. Not to mention the users will have a hard time selecting an appropriate value, even if you sort them alphabetically.

You would be much better off using an input text box instead of a dropdown.

`jQueryUI` has some nice [autocomplete features](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) that would improve not only the performance of your web application, but also make the user experience much more bearable. I would any day prefer to type out one of the 10,000 options provided to me than search for them in a dropdown using a mouse and select them.

[Here's an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le3Ej/1/) with ~8.5k records for a performance test.

Comment: Clearly from his plunker the browser *cannot* handle a large number of values in a plain dropdown list though. The only thing changing from his first example to his second is a buttload of more `<option>` nodes.

Comment: You're right, which is why I suggested using `jQueryUI's autocomplete` for such scenarios instead.

Comment: Alex and Chirag64, would it be better solution to use typeahead(autocomplete) http://plnkr.co/edit/3BxKUl1F4DPvgkg28qho?p=preview instead of jQueryUI because I've already integrated angular UI Bootstrap with my projec. 

And the use case is literally to select the appropriate data (option) from the provided list.

Comment: Hi orif, this should work well too as long as it doesn't affect the performance. You can use some custom JavaScript validation to make sure that the value entered by the user in the textbox exists in the array. This would be the same as making sure the user selects the appropriate option from the provided list and no other value.

Answer (score 1):

Let me quickly tell you few points:

1. It is a usability bug to scroll through 10K records. Consider someone going through 10K options and selecting the one which they want. Not a good idea.
2. Performance issue:

   - If the options were rendered from a back-end in a traditional way (non-Angular way) then it would just take time to load but after that the performance won't be such an issue.
   - Since, you are using AngularJS with `ng-options`, the options are populated in the front-end and you have all the data in Angular's scope. To perform, two-way binding, Angular always does a dirty-checking in each '**[digest cycle](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)**' which loops through each and every data element in $scope and causes that delay.

### Solution:

1. Use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)'s "**Loading Remote Data**". Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes.
2. Consider using the AngularUI's [Select2 wrapper](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) instead of directly using it.